# Fastcgi and version detection in HHVM

Tags: php, facebook, fastcgi, hhvm

I recently install HHVM using git clone, and I have also installed fastcgi and configured it for Apache 2.4, but still I am not able to run files on HHVM server.

```
 sudo hhvm -m server -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000
```

I run the above and get the following error

`WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
  E0410 00:38:32.074034 21849 fastcgi-session.cpp:562] FastCGI protocol: received an       invalid record`

I have install Fastcgi via

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fastcgi
```

and when I run

```
sudo apt-get install hhvm-fastcgi
```

I get this error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hhvm-fastcgi : Depends: hhvm (>= 2.3.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

but I type `hhvm --version` on command line it shows the following:

`HipHop VM 3.0.0-dev (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g39a0d45681b1404e19427f8cdd214c273d0a601d
Repo schema: b602fe3a78ec9eec7b65ec874110b9323ceabf88`

Update: my custom sites-enabled configuration

```
   <VirtualHost *:80 >

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ProxyPassMatch / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/
   </VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My Apache config file

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300

 KeepAlive On

 MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

 KeepAliveTimeout 5

 User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
 Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
 HostnameLookups Off
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn

 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
 Include ports.conf
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
 </Directory>

 <Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
  </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
  </Directory>
  AccessFileName .htaccess

  <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
  </FilesMatch>


   LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""         vhost_combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
   LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
   LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

   IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
   Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Comment: As you installed hhvm from git-clone, your package manager knows nothing about it probably? Add the hhvm deb repository and install it via your package manager is probably easier. Helpful? (You should find this explained on their website for Ubuntu or Debian)

Comment: The current HHVM version is 3.0.1. You can also install it via your packagemanager on a lot of dists. Also there is no need for installing `php5-fastcgi`. Maybe try uninstalling all hhvm* packages and compile/install it new.

Comment: No success @PKeidel. I tried every permutation (Atleast from my perspective)...

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the `hhvm-fastcgi` package. I need to kill that. Where did you find the docs for it?

The invalid record thing looks like you are hitting the fastcgi server in the wrong way. Pasting your apache config would be helpful. Did you exactly follow https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI ?

Comment: i found the docs from [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI) i have updated my apache config